# How to log OkHttp log to Crashlytics

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, crashlytics, okhttp

I am trying to use OkHttp to log to Crashlytics by the use of interception because some of my clients are getting 500 error and I want to complete details of what they are posting and getting in the response. Just like OkHttp shows in the logs of Android Studio.

I tried to log details when the 200 error occurs but no success.

```
@Module
public class DIModule {

MyApplication application;

public DIModule(MyApplication application) {
    this.application = application;
}
public DIModule()
{

}

@Singleton
@Provides
OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging).addInterceptor(new HeaderInterceptor())
            .build();
}
@Singleton
@Provides
Retrofit getRetro(OkHttpClient client) {

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Here we are using the GsonConverterFactory to directly convert json data to object
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())

            .build();
}

@Singleton
@Provides
Context provideApplicationContext()
{
    return application;
}

@Singleton
@Provides
MSharedPref getSharedPreferences(Context app)
{
    return new MSharedPref(app);
}

class HeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor
{
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException
    {
        Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();

        String token="No Value";
        if(StaticData.loginResponse!=null)
            token=StaticData.loginResponse.getAccess_token();

        builder.header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token)
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json");

        Response response=chain.proceed(builder.build());

        if(response.code()==200)
        {
            Log.d("test67","ooooooooooooooooooo"+response);
            //here I will log
        }

        return response;

    }
}

}
```

Log.d() is showing 
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://........./api/user}

but I want to log something like 
[image: log]

to crashlytics.

Will I get all those logs of OkHttp from the response or am I on the wrong way. Logging non fatal by `Crashlytics.logException(e);` also only take Throwable. So how I will do it?

Please Help..

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: I am also looking to log retrofit responses (400s and 500s) to Firebase Crashlytics but haven't found a method to add at Retrofit level so it is scalable. Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done to approach this case.
First, I created a custom logging exception that accepts a request object called `CustomLoggingException` and it only calls the exception main constructor with the request object as a String

```
public class CustomLoggingException extends Exception {
public CustomLoggingException(Request builderRequest, String body) {
    super(builderRequest.toString() + body);
}}
```

**Note** that I am also passing the body as a String because you will encounter the problem that the request string doesn't log the body content but it only logs the object type.

**So** I am checking for the body if it's not null then get its String content.

```
if (builderRequest.body() != null) 
        body = stringifyRequestBody(builderRequest.body());
```

and the stringifyRequestBody function that will get you the body as a String

```
private String stringifyRequestBody(RequestBody body) {
    try {
        BufferedSink buffer = new Buffer();
        body.writeTo(buffer);
        return buffer.getBuffer().readUtf8();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.d("Failed to stringify request body: " + e.getMessage());
        return "";
    }
}
```

After that you just log that exception to Crashlytics with these two inputs

```
Crashlytics.logException(new CustomLoggingException(builderRequest, body));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Crashlytics you can also log messages using Crashlytics.log(String), and these messages are only sent if a fatal error occurs or you record and exception manually using Crashlytics.recordException(throwable)

You can record a throwable when a 500 error occurs and all the messages you have logged before will be found in the logs tab in the reported non fatal error in Crashlytics

[image]

Here's an example for how to log an Okhttp request to to a string

```
   private fun stringifyRequestBody(request: Request): String? {
    if (request.body != null) {
        return try {
            val copy = request.newBuilder().build()
            val buffer = Buffer()
            copy.body!!.writeTo(buffer)
            buffer.readUtf8()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            "failed to stringify Request body"
        }
    }
    return ""
}


  fun logRequest(request: Request) {
    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        crashlytics.log("Request$request")
        crashlytics.log("RequestBody${stringifyRequestBody(request)}")
    }
}
```